# I am trying to run my script in startup.py but it says iface is not define, it works tho in script console

Tags: pyqgis

I have a working code and but it runs well only when I click on the run script button in QGIS. Here is the code:

```
import socket
import datetime
import qgis.utils

global layer
global items, clickStatus
items = []
#methods
def layer_changed():
    print('layer changed')
    global layer 
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    print('active layer set'+layer.name())
    clicked = AlreadyClicked(layer.name())
    trigger_signals(clicked)

def trigger_signals(clicked):
    print('Global layer is: '+layer.name())
    if not clicked:
        print("opening signals for layer: "+layer.name())
        layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(layer_attribute_value_changed)


#signals
def layer_attribute_value_changed(fid, atridx, val):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    print(str(local_ip)+' is writing to file...')
    output_file = open('\\\\5.16.78.13\\e\\log.txt', 'a')
    output_file.write(str(local_ip)+","+str(datetime.datetime.now())+',Layer name: '+layer.name()+',Feature id: '+str(fid)+',New Value: '+str(val)+',Attribute Index: '+str(atridx)+'\n')
    output_file.close()
    print('an attribute was changed in layer'+layer.name())
    
def AlreadyClicked(x):
    if x in items:
        return True
    else:
        items.append(x)
        return False


#events
qgis.utils.iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(layer_changed)
```

Now, I get this.

```
NameError: name 'iface' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ictba/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/startup.py", line 12, in layer_changed
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
NameError: name 'iface' is not defined
```

Comment: when I did this: qgis.utils.iface, I got an error: No module named 'qgis.utils.iface. Then when I did the from qgis.utils import iface, I received this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'